# Is it better to implement one-to-many relationship using tables as arrays?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, query-optimization, relationship

Recently, I was studying database designing and learning relationships in databases. So, for example, imagine an app that is for music management and basically there are albums and tracks and each album has many tracks but each track has one album. As I know it should be done like this:

Tracks:

| id | name | album_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1 | 1 |
| 2 | Test2 | 1 |
| 3 | Test3 | 2 |
| 4 | Test4 | 1 |
| 5 | Test5 | 2 |

Albums:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Album1 |
| 2 | Album2 |

It's a basic one-to-many relationship. But, if I want to get a list of all tracks that an album has, I should run a query on all rows on the Tracks table and select those with matching id which also means processing ones with non-matching id. What if instead, each album had an array of tracks in the table as a column? So this can't be done but I can create a table for each album called for example "Album1_Tracks" and store tracks in there and add a column to the Albums table called "Table_Name" to identify the table when querying. The model will look as following:

Album1_Tracks:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1 |
| 2 | Test2 |
| 3 | Test4 |

Album2_Tracks:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Test3 |
| 2 | Test5 |

Albums:

| id | name | Table_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Album1 | Album1_Tracks |
| 2 | Album2 | album2_Tracks |

In this case, whenever I want to get a list of all tracks in an album, I only need to get the table name with a query and then get all records in that table without checking anything. Although finding the album name of a specific track in this design would be too inefficient, if I only want to get a list of all tracks in the album and not vice-versa, is this design better in case of query performance?

Edit: `JOIN` is usually used for this purpose but will this design achieve better performance than `JOIN`?

Comment: Joins are something that relational databases are extremely good at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, SQL works far better with a small number of tables than it does with a design that calls for a new table for each instance of a particular entity.

In your case the entity in question is the album. Put all your albums in one table with separate id values, according to your first design.

A query of the form

```
SELECT Track.Name, Album.Name
  FROM Track
  JOIN Album ON Track.Album_ID = Album.ID
 WHERE Album.Name = 'Revolver'
```

is astonishingly efficient. It will exploit an SQL index on the Album_ID column. If the index is present it will avoid the full table scan ("processing ones with non-matching IDs") you mention in your question.

There's another problem with your second approach: In SQL queries, the names of tables must be constant. You cannot use the value of a column as the name of a table (or column or database).

Thousands (truly) of years of programmer time have gone into making SQL queries efficient. There's almost nothing left to be gained from trying to outsmart the query optimizer software in MySQL Or other RDBMS software.